# remove empty numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
array([], shape=(0, 4), dtype=float64)
```

How can I remove this array in a multidimensional array?
I tried

```
import numpy as np

if array == []:
    np.delete(array)
```

But, the multidimensional array still has this empty array.

EDIT:
The input is

```
new_array = [array([], shape=(0, 4), dtype=float64), 
   array([[-0.97,  0.99, -0.98, -0.93 ],
   [-0.97, -0.99,  0.59, -0.93 ],
   [-0.97,  0.99, -0.98, -0.93 ],
   [ 0.70 ,  1,  0.60,  0.65]]), array([[-0.82,  1,  0.61, -0.63],
   [ 0.92, -1,  0.77,  0.88],
   [ 0.92, -1,  0.77,  0.88],
   [ 0.65, -1,  0.73,  0.85]]), array([], shape=(0, 4), dtype=float64)]
```

The expected output after removing the empty arrays is:

```
new array = [array([[-0.97,  0.99, -0.98, -0.93 ],
   [-0.97, -0.99,  0.59, -0.93 ],
   [-0.97,  0.99, -0.98, -0.93 ],
   [ 0.70 ,  1,  0.60,  0.65]]), 
   array([[-0.82,  1,  0.61, -0.63],
   [ 0.92, -1,  0.77,  0.88],
   [ 0.92, -1,  0.77,  0.88],
   [ 0.65, -1,  0.73,  0.85]])]
```

Comment: There is no `shape` keyword in `numpy.array` what function is that array ?

Comment: I just printed new_array which I constructed using new_array.append(array). And that's the output of the print.

Comment: @AnandSKumar: That's a NumPy `ndarray`.  The `shape` and `dtype` are included in the `repr` when they can't be inferred (for example when there's a zero-length dimension, as here).  `np.zeros((0, 4), dtype=float)` would have a `repr` like that, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new_array`, as printed, looks like a list of arrays.  And even if it were an array, it would be a 1d array of dtype=object.

`==[]` is not the way to check for an empty array:

```
In [10]: x=np.zeros((0,4),float)
In [11]: x
Out[11]: array([], shape=(0, 4), dtype=float64)
In [12]: x==[]
Out[12]: False
In [14]: 0 in x.shape  # check if there's a 0 in the shape
Out[14]: True
```

Check the syntax for `np.delete`.  It requires an array, an index and an axis, and returns another array.  It does not operate in place.

If `new_array` is a list, a list comprehension would do a nice job of removing the `[]` arrays:

```
In [33]: alist=[x, np.ones((2,3)), np.zeros((1,4)),x]

In [34]: alist
Out[34]: 
[array([], shape=(0, 4), dtype=float64), array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([], shape=(0, 4), dtype=float64)]

In [35]: [y for y in alist if 0 not in y.shape]
Out[35]: 
[array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]), array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])]
```

It would also work if `new_array` was a 1d array:

```
new_array=np.array(alist)
newer_array = np.array([y for y in new_array if 0 not in y.shape])
```

To use `np.delete` with `new_array`, you have to specify which elements:

```
In [47]: np.delete(new_array,[0,3])
Out[47]: 
array([array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]),
       array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])], dtype=object)
```

to find `[0,3]` you could use `np.where`:

```
np.delete(new_array,np.where([y.size==0 for y in new_array]))
```

Better yet, skip the `delete` and `where` and go with a boolean mask

```
new_array[np.array([y.size>0 for y in new_array])]
```

I don't think there's a way of identifying these 'emtpy' arrays without a list comprehension, since you have to check the shape or size property, not the element's data.  Also there's a limit as to what kinds of math you can do across elements of an object array.  It's more like a list than a 2d array.

Comment: I prefer `x.size == 0` to `0 in x.shape`: it seems more direct.

Comment: Interesting... it got me thinking about the 'empty list'  Take ...  
>>> x = np.asanyarray( [] , dtype='float64')
>>> y = a.reshape((0,4,4))
>>>print("\nx:  {!r:} shape:{!r:}\ny:  {!r:}".format(x,x.shape,y))    
  if you try to merge the first and the last array with the middle, you end up with only the middle as long as you reshape the original array derived from the empty list to match the shape of the middle array.  I can find no documentation discussing combining arrays of 0 size, I know you can't if the shape differs.

Comment: `np.concatenate([np.ones((2,4)),np.zeros((0,4))])` effectively removes the `(0,4)` array.  As long as the other dimensions match, `concatenate` has no problems with `0` dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

I had initially an array (3,11,11) and after a multprocessing using pool.map my array was transformed in a list like this:

```
[array([], shape=(0, 11, 11), dtype=float64),
array([[[ 0.35318114,  0.36152024,  0.35572945,  0.34495254,  0.34169853,
       0.36553977,  0.34266126,  0.3492261 ,  0.3339431 ,  0.34759375,
       0.33490712],...
```

if a convert this list in an array the shape was (3,), so I used:

```
myarray = np.vstack(mylist)
```

and this returned my first 3d array with the original shape (3,11,11).

Answer (score 0):

Delete takes the multidimensional array as a parameter. Then you need to specify the subarray to delete and the axis it's on. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

```
np.delete(new_array,<obj indicating subarray to delete (perhaps an array of integers in your case)>, 0)
```

Also, note that the deletion is not in-place.